# android Media player not reading some mp3 url

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i've created a playlist based on Media Player class. The thing is that it succeed in reading some mp3 url and it doesn't for another ones. 
For example here is a directory of mp3 i've uploaded but no one is working:

http://rajaapp12.0fees.us/gbv3/

in the other hands an mp3 which work:

http://mp3.mp3zik.com/music/Music-Rap/Casa%20Verde%202009/track%20(14).mp3

I don't think there is a problem with the code since it works already witch some url, but here is the most iportant part of it :

```
public void beginLrcPlay(){
    killMediaPlayer();
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(songEnCours.getSource_128());
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
                if (mTimer == null) {
                    mTimer = new Timer();
                    mTask = new LrcTask();
                    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTask, 0, mPalyTimerDuration);
                }
            }
        });
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //fin musique ajouter action !

                stopLrcPlay();
                chantSuivant();
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_selector_btn_play);
            }
        });
        mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(onBufferingUpdateListener);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us some code so we can help you better :)

Comment: i've edited the post, done!

Comment: That songEncours.getSource_128 is a method of yours? If yes, can you show the code?

Comment: it's a simple getter nothing else, and it works fine here is a log:  `08-29 22:00:22.734  16985-16985/com.appV/source_128﹕ http://mp3.mp3zik.com/music/Music-Rap/Casa Verde 2009/track (14).mp3`
`08-29 22:00:33.985  16985-16985/com.appV/source_128﹕ http://rajaapp12.0fees.us/vocec3/FER9A_MECHHOURA.mp3`
the first url is working, not the second O.o !

Comment: It's indeed strange, I've tryed here and it didn't work as well, but it should! Maybe the webhost service you're using it's a free one and they are blocking external access or something?.. (I don't know if I'm saying something stupid but I once got problems with that free hosts too).

Comment: :/ and do you know another free host where it works??

Comment: No, I don't.. But hey, keep in mind that I didn't said the problem is with the host, what I said is that it can be a possibility...
Store one of the .mp3 you want in some place on your device and try to play it from that location, maybe the problem is with .mp3 itself..